# Using PRAW, "print submission.add_comment(response)" receives Syntax error

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm building a reddit bot using PRAW, But I'm getting a Syntax error after running my script. My script is here:

```
import praw
import cleverbot   
cb = cleverbot.Session()
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='XXXXXXXXXX',
                     client_secret='XXXXXXXXXXXXx',
                     password='XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                     user_agent='XXXXXXXXXXX',
                     username='XXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                     
submissions = r.get_subreddit('XXXXXXXXXXXXXX').get_new(limit=1)
for submission in submissions:
        t = submission.title
        response = cb.Ask(t)
        print(t)
        print submission.add_comment(response)
```

Python gives me this message after running my script:

```
  File "bot.py", line 15
    print submission.add_comment(response)
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If this is Python3, then `print` is a function, not a statement - you missed the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error is caused by not using parentheses to call `print`.

You must have found an outdated PRAW tutorial because the PRAW methods you're calling haven't existed since version 3. Here's what you're trying to do, with up-to-date PRAW methods:

```
submissions = reddit.subreddit('XXXXXXXXXXXXXX').new(limit=1)
for submission in submissions:
    t = submission.title
    response = cb.Ask(t)
    print(t)
    print(submission.reply(response))
```